# Is it possible to start all SVG Keyframe-animations when hovering over one path?

Tags: javascript, svg-animate

i´ve been looking for a while now but i just cant find anything that helps me with my Problem. Im looking for an opportunity to start mulitple Keyframe-animations when hovering over just one path of the SVG, which paths are animated.
I tried things like changing the animation-play-state when hovering, however this again only works for one animation.

```html
<svg id`="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 164.03 164.59">
      <defs>
         <style>
             .cls-1,.cls-2,.cls-4,.cls-5{stroke:#000;stroke-miterlimit:10}.cls- 
             2,.cls-4{fill:none}.cls-2{stroke-width:2px}.cls-4{stroke- 
             width:.75px}.cls-5{stroke-width:.18px}

      /* color sun and hide it */
      @keyframes sonne{
      0%{
      opacity: 1;
      }
      50%{
      fill: #ffc142;
      opacity:1
      }
      80%{
      fill: #ffc142;
      opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
      fill: #ffc142;
      opacity: 0;
      }
      }



      /* color sunrays and hide */
      @keyframes sonnenStrahlen{
      0%{
      opacity: 1;
      }
      50%{
      stroke: #ffc142;
      opacity:1
      }
      80%{
      stroke: #ffc142;
      opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
      stroke: #ffc142;
      opacity: 0;
      }
      }

      /* make cloud visible and colored */
      @keyframes  wolke {
      0% {

      opacity: 0;
      }
      50% {
      transform:  translate(10px,-114.24px) scale(0.6);
      opacity: 0;

      }
      70% {
      stroke: #13596e;
      fill: #13596e;
      }
      100% {
      opacity: 1;
      stroke: #13596e;
      fill: #13596e;
      transform:  translate(-61px,-114.24px) scale(1);
      }
      }

      /* show roof */
      @keyframes  dach {
      0% {
      opacity: 0;
      }
      50% {
      opacity: 0;
      }
      100% {
      opacity: 1;
      }
      }

      /* move rider and horse*/
      @keyframes reiten1 {
      0% {
      transform:  translate(-61px,-114.24px);
      opacity: 1;
      }

      90% {
      opacity: 1;
      transform:  translate(58px,-114.24px);
      }
      100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform:  translate(58px,-114.24px);


      }
      }

      /* move back 2nd rider and horse*/
      @keyframes reiten2 {
      0% {
      opacity: 0;
      }
      50% {
      opacity: 0;
      }
      70% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translate(-2px,0px);
      }
      75% {

      opacity:1;


      }
      100% {
      opacity: 1;
      /*transform:  translate(-119px,0px);*/

      }
      }






      #sonne {
      animation: sonne 4.5s normal;
      opacity: 0;
      }

      #sonnenStrahlen {
      animation: sonnenStrahlen 4.5s normal;
      opacity: 0;
      }

      #wolke {
      animation: wolke 9.5s normal;
      stroke: #13596e;
      fill: #13596e;

      }

      #regenTropfen {
      animation: wolke 9.5s normal;
      stroke: #13596e;
      fill: #13596e;
      }

      #regenTropfenRest {
      animation: wolke 9.5s normal;
      stroke: #13596e;
      fill: #13596e;
      }

      #dach {
      animation: dach 9.5s normal;
      opacity: 1;

      }

      #reiter11 {
      animation: reiten1 4.5s normal;
      opacity: 0;
      }

      #reiter12 {
      animation: reiten1 4.5s normal;
      opacity: 0;
      }

      #reiter14 {
      animation: reiten1 4.5s normal;
      opacity: 0;
      }

      #reiter21 {
      opacity:  1;
      animation: reiten2 13.5s normal;
      transform: translate(-119px, 0px);
      }

      #reiter22 {
      opacity:  1;
      animation: reiten2 13.5s normal;
      transform: translate(-119px, 0px);
      }

      #reiter24 {
      opacity:  1;
      animation: reiten2 13.5s normal;
      transform: translate(-119px, 0px);
      }

      #zügel1 {
      fill: #1c1c1c;
      animation: reiten1 4.5s normal;
      opacity: 0;
      }

      #zügel2 {
      fill: #1c1c1c;
      opacity:  1;
      animation: reiten2 13.5s normal;
      transform: translate(-119px, 0px);
      }











    </style>
      </defs>
      <path id="boden" class="cls-1" d="M1 154.43h162v9.67H1z"/>
      <path id="linkeWand" class="cls-2" d="M1 120.2v44.33"/>
      <path id="reiter11" d="M63.38 247.82a13.48 13.48 0 0 1 2-4 6.22 6.22 0 0 1 2.13-1.75 5 5 0 0 1 1.75-.25s2.93-.1 5.63 0a4.38 4.38 0 0 0 .63 1.25 5 5 0 0 0 1.38 1.25 16.82 16.82 0 0 0 1.88 1c1.08.53 1.35.63 1.38.88 0 0 0 .22-1.12 1.25a10.74 10.74 0 0 1-1.12 1.63c-.45.53-.69.71-.75 1.13a2.31 2.31 0 0 0 .38 1.38 2.76 2.76 0 0 0 .45.62c.32.33.58.42.55.5s-1.38-.38-1.87.13c-.24.25-.12.58-.12 1.25 0 1.16-.4 1.41-.62 2.63a8.3 8.3 0 0 0 0 2.63 24.63 24.63 0 0 0 .75 3.25s.29 1.1.63 3.25a2 2 0 0 1-.12 1.38 1.78 1.78 0 0 1-1.37.86s-.35 0-1.75-.86a16.57 16.57 0 0 1-2.12-8.37c.09-2.86 1-4.91.5-5.12s-2.32 2.08-2.87 4.25a8.76 8.76 0 0 0-.25 1.88 16 16 0 0 0 .25 2.13c.15 1.36 0 1.26.13 2.88.11 1.31.24 1.62 0 2.13a2 2 0 0 1-1.47.99c-.95.15-2-1.1-2-1.11l-.5-10.37a20.51 20.51 0 0 0 2.25-4.58c.82-2.75.33-5.47 0-5.5-.14 0-.24.44-1 3-1 3.44-1.24 4-1.87 4.38a2.52 2.52 0 0 1-2.91-.5c-.56-.71 0-2.32 1.16-5.5z" transform="translate(-61 -114.24)"/>
      <path id="reiter12" d="M80.38 251.94c.57-.09.67-.56 1.63-1.75.38-.47 1.21-1.36 2.88-3.12.82-.87 1.19-1.24 1.13-1.75s-.41-.68-1.12-1.25a24.18 24.18 0 0 0-2.25-1.5 7.35 7.35 0 0 0 .11-1.07 12.62 12.62 0 0 0-.11-2.43c0-.25-.09-.43 0-.5s.54.3 1.25.75a8.41 8.41 0 0 0 2.63 1c.32.06.51.08.51.08.6.06.8-.05.87 0s-.08.36-1.12 1.5c-2.08-.45-2.57-.39-2.62-.25s.83.62 2.13 1.88c.91.89 1.08 1.28 1.13 1.63a2.44 2.44 0 0 1-.5 1.63 10 10 0 0 1-2.25 2.5c-2.17 1.88-3.34 2.91-3.12 3.38.09.18.6.2 1.63.25a21.39 21.39 0 0 0 2.79-.1h.21c.93 0-.12 13.76-.12 13.76a.87.87 0 0 0 0 .11c0 .79 1.17 1.32 1.25 1.36s1.42.62 2.13 0 .42-1.49.38-1.86c-.59-4.61.13-14.44.13-14.5l5.5-9.25a4.93 4.93 0 0 0 2.5 0 3.33 3.33 0 0 0 2-1.12c.6-.84.2-1.54.88-2.12.52-.45.92-.17 1.25-.62 0 0 .21-.29.13-2l-4.75-3.62c.24-1.36.44-3 0-3.12s-1 1-2.37 2.75c0 0-.31.4-5.87 6.5a2.74 2.74 0 0 1-1.25-.12c-.74-.26-.9-.72-1.75-1.12s-.79-.11-1.25-.37c-.72-.41-.72-1.06-1.5-2.75-.62-1.34-.94-2-1.62-2.37a4.38 4.38 0 0 0-1.87-.25c-1.55 0-2.33-.06-2.87.38a3.1 3.1 0 0 0-.75 2.5c0 6.48 0 7.19.38 7.63a11.4 11.4 0 0 0 2.25 1.63c1.73 1.11 2.58 1.36 2.63 2 0 .27-.12.47-1.37 1.75-1.56 1.59-1.87 1.8-1.87 2.25a2.08 2.08 0 0 0 1.99 1.69z" transform="translate(-61 -114.24)"/>
      <path   id="zügel1" d="M97.13 238.69c-.44.35-.26.85-.95 1.58-.1.1-.18.18-.18.29 0 .36 1 .8 1.75.63a2.63 2.63 0 0 0 1.7-1.92v-.16c0-.01-1.52-1.05-2.32-.42z" transform="translate(-61 -114.24)" fill="#fff"/>
      <path  id="reiter14" d="M77.48 230.48a2.71 2.71 0 0 0 1.81.88 2.26 2.26 0 0 0 2-.85 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 .38-2c0-.05 0-.08 2 0v-.65l-1.79-.08a1.65 1.65 0 0 0 0-.42 2.36 2.36 0 0 0-1.08-1.5 2.57 2.57 0 0 0-1.5-.49A2.87 2.87 0 0 0 77 227a3.08 3.08 0 0 0-.27 1 3.13 3.13 0 0 0 .75 2.48z" transform="translate(-61 -114.24)"/>
      <path id="bande" class="cls-2" d="M1 136.09h162"/>
      <circle id="sonne" cx="8.98" cy="19.93" r="7.88"/>
      <path id="sonnenStrahlen" class="cls-4" d="M8.98 32.56v8M21.4 19.93h8M16.57 27.73l5.66 5.65"/>
      <path id="rechteWand" class="cls-2" d="M163.03 164.56v-44.33"/>
      <path id="regenTropfen" class="cls-5" d="M123.56 151.05c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.23-.49-1.14-.93-1.09z" transform="translate(-61 -114.24)"/>
      <path id="wolke" class="cls-1" d="M168 139c-5.09 2.58-4.88 5.49-8 6-5.16.86-10.27-6.11-10.7-6.72-2.69-3.76-3.54-8-3.76-7.9s3.27 7.51.31 11.33c-1.2 1.55-3.12 2.05-4.6 2.43-2.68.7-4.83.28-8.3-.43-6.56-1.35-9.84-2-10.43-2.21-5.8-1.81-16.37-5.09-16.66-10.26-.1-1.7 1-3 3.33-5.66 2.15-2.48 6.83-7.91 11.62-7.12 3.49.57 4.22 4 7.86 4a8.14 8.14 0 0 0 4.57-1.83c1.27-.83 12.71-8.14 19.48-5.25 3.89 1.66 4 5.72 7.61 6 2.48.18 3.29-1.65 6.1-2.52 5.94-1.83 15.2 2.42 15.84 7.94.47 4.07-3.82 8.07-6.9 9.78-2.99 1.63-3.92.7-7.37 2.42z" transform="translate(-61 -114.24)"/>
      <path id="regenTropfenRest" class="cls-5" d="M112.22 159.1c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.19-.48-1.13-.93-1.09zM122.57 163.09c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.18-.5-1.13-.93-1.09zM142 162.95c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.05-.23-.45-1.13-.93-1.09zM147.47 154.8c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.23-.48-1.13-.93-1.09zM130.53 153.2c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.23-.46-1.13-.93-1.09zM140.3 150.27c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.23-.48-1.13-.93-1.09zM132 165.57c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.13-.23-.53-1.13-.93-1.09zM148.54 166.83c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.22-.47-1.12-.93-1.09zM164.18 164.54c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.11-.23-.48-1.13-.93-1.09zM167 154.8c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.06-.23-.46-1.13-.93-1.09zM156.5 156.95c-.68.06-1.17 2.22-1.17 2.22s-.53.9-.35 1.4a1.71 1.71 0 0 0 2.22.47c.9-.59.6-2.21.23-3-.08-.23-.48-1.13-.93-1.09z" transform="translate(-61 -114.24)"/>
      <path id="dach" stroke-width="2" stroke="#000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M1 89.09l81-24.33 81 24.33v31.11-31.11H1v31.11"/>
    
      <path id="reiter21" d="M161.7 133.6c1.1 3.2 1.7 4.8 1.1 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.9.5c-.6-.4-.9-1-1.9-4.4-.7-2.6-.8-3-1-3-.3 0-.8 2.8 0 5.5a20.5 20.5 0 0 0 2.3 4.6l-.5 10.4s-1 1.2-2 1a2 2 0 0 1-1.5-1c-.2-.4-.1-.8 0-2l.1-3a16 16 0 0 0 .3-2 8.8 8.8 0 0 0-.3-2c-.5-2.1-2.3-4.4-2.8-4.2s.4 2.3.5 5.1a16.6 16.6 0 0 1-2.1 8.4 5 5 0 0 1-1.8.9 1.8 1.8 0 0 1-1.3-.9 2 2 0 0 1-.1-1.4l.6-3.2a24.6 24.6 0 0 0 .7-3.3 8.3 8.3 0 0 0 0-2.6c-.2-1.2-.6-1.5-.6-2.6 0-.7.1-1-.1-1.3-.5-.5-1.8 0-1.9-.1s.3-.2.6-.5a2.8 2.8 0 0 0 .4-.6 2.3 2.3 0 0 0 .4-1.4c0-.4-.3-.6-.7-1.1a10.7 10.7 0 0 1-1.2-1.7c-1-1-1-1.2-1-1.2 0-.3.2-.4 1.3-1a16.8 16.8 0 0 0 1.9-1 5 5 0 0 0 1.4-1.2 4.4 4.4 0 0 0 .6-1.2 92 92 0 0 1 5.6 0 5 5 0 0 1 1.8.2 6.2 6.2 0 0 1 2.1 1.8 13.5 13.5 0 0 1 2 4z"/>
      <path id="reiter22" d="M144.7 137.7a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7c0-.4-.4-.7-2-2.2-1.2-1.3-1.3-1.5-1.3-1.8 0-.6 1-.9 2.6-2a11.4 11.4 0 0 0 2.3-1.6c.4-.5.4-1.2.4-7.7a3.1 3.1 0 0 0-.8-2.5c-.5-.4-1.3-.3-2.9-.3a4.4 4.4 0 0 0-1.8.2c-.7.4-1 1-1.6 2.4-.8 1.7-.8 2.3-1.5 2.7-.5.3-.4 0-1.3.4s-1 .9-1.7 1.1a2.7 2.7 0 0 1-1.3.2l-5.9-6.5c-1.3-1.8-1.9-3-2.3-2.8s-.3 1.8 0 3.1l-4.8 3.6.1 2c.4.5.8.2 1.3.7.7.5.3 1.2.9 2a3.3 3.3 0 0 0 2 1.2 5 5 0 0 0 2.5 0l5.5 9.3s.7 9.8.1 14.5a1.9 1.9 0 0 0 .4 1.8c.7.6 2 0 2.1 0s1.3-.6 1.3-1.3a.9.9 0 0 0 0-.2s-1-13.7-.2-13.7h.3a21.4 21.4 0 0 0 2.7 0c1 0 1.6 0 1.7-.2.2-.4-1-1.5-3.1-3.3a10 10 0 0 1-2.3-2.5 2.4 2.4 0 0 1-.5-1.7c0-.3.2-.7 1.1-1.6 1.3-1.3 2.2-1.7 2.2-1.9s-.6-.2-2.7.3c-1-1.2-1.1-1.5-1-1.5h.8l.5-.1a8.4 8.4 0 0 0 2.6-1l1.3-.8v.5a12.6 12.6 0 0 0-.1 2.5 7.3 7.3 0 0 0 0 1 24.2 24.2 0 0 0-2.2 1.5c-.7.6-1 .8-1 1.3s.2.9 1 1.7l3 3.2c1 1.1 1 1.6 1.6 1.7z"/>
      <path id="zügel2" d="M125.6 124.9v.1a2.6 2.6 0 0 0 1.7 2c.7 0 1.7-.3 1.7-.7l-.1-.3c-.7-.7-.6-1.2-1-1.6-.8-.6-2.3.5-2.3.5z"/>
      <path id="reiter24" d="M148.3 113.8a3 3 0 0 0-.3-1 2.9 2.9 0 0 0-2.3-1.7 2.6 2.6 0 0 0-1.5.5 2.4 2.4 0 0 0-1 1.5 1.6 1.6 0 0 0 0 .4l-1.8.1v.7h2a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 .3 2 2.3 2.3 0 0 0 2 .8 2.7 2.7 0 0 0 1.8-.9 3.1 3.1 0 0 0 .8-2.4z"/>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add two keyframes to one animation separating them with a   **,**

```
yourshape:hover{
animation: 
first-animation 1s,
second-animation 2s;
}
```

and then ofcourse with your own syles and animations.